# Неправильное отображение символов в БД

Tags: php_pdo, iconv, кодировка, php

Добрый день!
Возникли трудности при работе с БД через PDO.
При создании записи через `prepare` и `execute` в базу попадают не русские символы, а "Ð˜ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ñ Ñ…Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð°".
Пробовал переводить через `iconv` и через `mb_convert_encoding`, но ничего толкового не получилось.
Прошу вас помочь.
Также уточню, я передаю данные через форму, через POST, и данные приходят в нормальном пригодочитаемом формате.

Comment: Кодировка базы данных соответствует записываемой?

Comment: Кодировки, кодировки, кодировки…
Файла, базы данных, заголовков…

Это первое, что нужно было проверить.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, буду пробовать.

Comment: В итоге нашел решение!
$pdo->query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");